# issue with configuring phabricator & nginx

Tags: php, nginx, phabricator

I installed phabricator on ubuntu using the install_ubunbu script from the phabricator site which apeared to have ran successfully.  I already had MySQL on the server - I have added the DB credentials in the default.conf.php file.  I copied the Nginx config from their site as well.  I added a listening port on port 82.  However, when I try to access the url/port in the browser, I get the following Nginx error message (from nginx logs):

**Error Message**

```
2014/04/30 12:41:35 [error] 14691#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: phabricator.xxxx.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
 "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.xxx.xxx.xxx:82"
```

**Nginx conf**

```
server {
       listen 82;  ### 520;
       listen [::]:82;
       server_name phabricator.xxxx.com;

       root /usr/local/phabricator/phabricator/webroot;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

       access_log /var/log/nginx/phabricator/access.log;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/phabricator/error.log;

      location / {
                index index.php;

                if ( !-f $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?__path__=/$1 last;
                    break;
                }
        }

       location ~ .php$ {
           fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
           fastcgi_index index.php;

           #custom environment variable
           fastcgi_param PHABRICATOR_ENV   "custom/myconfig";  ##change this

           #required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
           fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;

           #variables to make the $_SERVER populate in PHP
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
           fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
           fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
           fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;

           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME      $fastcgi_script_name;

           fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
           fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE  nginx/$nginx_version;

           fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR      $remote_Addr;
   }
}
```

Any ideas on troubleshooting this or if I need to follow additional steps for setting up phabricator would be appreciated.

Comment: pilot error - php5-fpm was not listening on 9000 - I was using the php5-fpm.sock instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was pilot error - php5-fpm was not listening on 9000 since I was using the php5-fpm.sock instead (configured in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/)

Comment: So how should I fix it?

Comment: are you running nginx in front of phabricator - if so, are you using php5-fpm and if so, are you using php5-fpm.sock?

Comment: I figured out, in my case, php-fpm was not running, so I had to do sudo service php-fpm start, that fixed my problem.

Comment: @user2002692 Had you been listening on php5-fpm.sock like myself, you'd fix it by editing /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and commenting out `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`. Replace that with `listen = 9000`, save, close, and restart php5-fpm. You can then check that it's listening on port 9000 by doing `netstat -na | grep 9000`